# vagrant puppet provision error

Tags: macos, vagrant, puppet

I've had no issues until last night where I can't provision anything. I keep getting

`` The `puppet` binary appears not to be in the PATH of the guest. This
could be because the PATH is not properly setup or perhaps Puppet is not
installed on this guest. Puppet provisioning can not continue without
Puppet properly installed. ``

Not sure what's gone wrong? Any ideas?

Comment: I suggest that you'd post your configuration, scripts, etc...

Comment: I've just tried to install via https://puphpet.com/